# Merge and sum array objects Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. I need to merge elements of the array if the `tag` property is the same and then sum the `counter` properties of those objects.

Here is my example array:

```
[
    {
        "tag": "#sala",
        "state": {
            "counter": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "tag": "#sala",
        "state": {
            "counter": 2
        }
    }
]
```

This is what the array should look like after merge:

```
[
    {
        "tag": "#sala",
        "state": {
            "counter": 3
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried to use reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array reduce function and inside the reduce call back use `findIndex` to check if the accumulator array have an object with same tag. If a object with same tag is found then update the counter in that object , otherwise push the current object in the accumulator array

```js
let data = [{
    "tag": "#sala",
    "state": {
      "counter": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "tag": "#sala",
    "state": {
      "counter": 2
    }
  }
];
let newData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findTagIndex = acc.findIndex(item => item.tag === curr.tag);
  if (findTagIndex === -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  } else {
    acc[findTagIndex].state.counter += curr.state.counter
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: I would request you to not spoon-feed users. This is just my POV hence requesting

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build an object mapping tags to counters and then use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) to convert the object back to your original array structure"

```js
let data = [{
    "tag": "#sala",
    "state": {
      "counter": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "tag": "#sala",
    "state": {
      "counter": 2
    }
  }
];

let newData = data.reduce(
  ( obj, { tag, state: { counter } } ) => ( obj[ tag ] = counter + (obj[ tag ] || 0), obj ), { }
);

// Object mapping tags to counter sums
console.log( newData );

// If you need your original array structure:
newData = Object.entries( newData ).map( ( [ key,value ]) => ( { tag: key, state: { counter: value } } ) );

console.log( newData );
```